# How to get the archive of the same tag name?

Tags: wordpress

As title, I've tried to search plugins, but not what I want.

What I want is like [this](http://tedwise.com/tag/osx).

Any plugin could do like that?
If not, could someone tell me how to implement this using php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file called tag.php, add the title using `<?php single_tag_title(); ?>` and then use a regular WordPress loop to display the titles.

Update:
Like this, for tag.php:

```
<?php single_tag_title(); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but single_tag_title() is just for single tag name, how to get all titles of this tag?

Comment: You found an answer using wp_query and custom parameters, which is fine if it works for you. I prefer using the template hierarchy as much as possible, that tends to make the code more stable imo.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is using WP_Query:

```
$tag_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=' . single_tag_title("", false) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowdays you can use `get_queried_object();` inside **archive.php** file to get tag data on page domain.com/tag/tagName.

According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object/